# Can I embed a JavaFX Application class inside a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jframe, extends

I am making a 'Weather Station' application, and I am using JavaFX to plot a streamed graph.  I want to know whether I can place the graph inside a JFrame along with other components I wish to have displayed and, if so, how.

**The class I want inside the `JFrame`**

```
public class JavaFXApplication6 extends Application
{

    private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> hourDataSeries;
    private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> minuteDataSeries;
    private NumberAxis xAxis;
    private Timeline animation;

    // more variables handling data manipulation based on time passing

    private void init(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        root.getChildren().add(createChart());

        // create timeline to add new data every 60th of second
        animation = new Timeline();
        animation.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000 / 60), 
                                     new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                                     {
                                        @Override
                                        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent)
                                        {
                                            // 6 minutes data per frame
                                            for (int count = 0; count < 6; count++)
                                            {
                                                nextTime();
                                                plotTime();
                                            }
                                        }
                                     }));

        animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    }

    protected LineChart<Number, Number> createChart()
    {

        // Code to setup chart and starting data and return it - substitute
        // with:
        return new LineChart(new NumberAxis(0, 24, 3), new NumberAxis(0, 100, 10));
    }

    private void nextTime()
    {
        // Code to advance time variables
    }

    private void plotTime() {
        // update data series' based on time passing
    }

    public void play()
    {
        animation.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop()
    {
        animation.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
        play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**The GUI class is a standard swing `JFrame`**

Comment: VWhat do you mean, "Generated"? If you are talking about a WindowBuilder or something of that nature you should learn Swing, and make the GUI manually.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Your question came to me in the review queue and I've made a few edits: a) Cut your code block down. See [creating a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - lots of very specific detail tends to distract. If you think I've removed anything crucial, please do add back in b) altered the title to give more information.  Finally - it's often useful to show where you've looked already (e.g. JavaFX tutorial) and why that hasn't helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include a `Scene` in a Swing application by placing it in a `JFXPanel`. [This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm#CHDIEEJE) has more details.

You cannot embed an `Application` subclass directly into a Swing application; the `Application` subclass is the startup class; it represents the actual application, not a UI element. So you will need to refactor your JavaFX code very slightly to make this work.

Specifically, I would define a class such as:

```
public class AnimatedChart
{

    private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> hourDataSeries;
    private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> minuteDataSeries;
    private NumberAxis xAxis;
    private Timeline animation;

    private Group view ;

    // more variables handling data manipulation based on time passing

    public AnimatedChart()
    {
        view = new Group();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(view));
        view.getChildren().add(createChart());

        // create timeline to add new data every 60th of second
        animation = new Timeline();
        animation.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000 / 60), 
                                     new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
                                     {
                                        @Override
                                        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent)
                                        {
                                            // 6 minutes data per frame
                                            for (int count = 0; count < 6; count++)
                                            {
                                                nextTime();
                                                plotTime();
                                            }
                                        }
                                     }));

        animation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    }

    public Parent getView() {
        return view ;
    }

    protected LineChart<Number, Number> createChart()
    {

        // Code to setup chart and starting data and return it - substitute
        // with:
        return new LineChart(new NumberAxis(0, 24, 3), new NumberAxis(0, 100, 10));
    }

    private void nextTime()
    {
        // Code to advance time variables
    }

    private void plotTime() {
        // update data series' based on time passing
    }

    public void play()
    {
        animation.play();
    }

    public void pause() {
        animation.pause();
    }
}
```

Then you can define an `Application` class:

```
public void AnimatedChartApp extends Application {

    private AnimatedChart animatedChart ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        animatedChart = new AnimatedChart();
        Scene scene = new Scene(animatedChart.getView());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        animatedChart.play();
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        animatedChart.stop();
    }
}
```

Or you can use it in a Swing application:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
frame.add(jfxPanel);
frame.setVisible(true);
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    AnimatedChart animatedChart = new AnimatedChart();
    Scene scene = new Scene(animatedChart.getView());
    jfxPanel.setScene(scene);
    animatedChart.play();
});
```